# Analyzing unzipped files on PythonAnywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

I have a python code that runs perfectly well on my computer, except that my laptop is very slow. I want to upload the code and run it on PythonAnywhere. (Not even sure if this is the best suited resource, but it is relatively easy to use!)

I have successfully uploaded some files and my code to my home directory, and the code runs ok. But since I have many files to analyze, I have uploaded a zip file, successfully upzipped it (to home/myname/part1) and saved my python code to the same directory. When I try to run my code in that directory, however, it does not work. In fact, the code does not return any error, it analyzes 2 blank files instead of the 100 or so I uploaded. And then it stops and exits as if the job was done.

Any ideas why? TIA!

If that matters, here is a condensed version of the code ("analysis" is not a command, but stands for more lines of analysis, all of which run fine on my computer):

```
import csv, re
from string import punctuation
import glob, io

csvfile=open("test.csv", "w", newline='', encoding='cp850', errors='replace')
writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):

    ###Open files and arrange them so that they are ready for pre-processing
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:

      analysis

      output=zip(file1, file_name, more_date)
      writer=csv.writer(open('test.csv','a',newline='', encoding='cp850', errors='replace'))
      writer.writerows(output)
      csvfile.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're not processing the files you think you're processing. Print the result of your glob so that you can verify that you're working in the directory you think you are.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed thought that the script would know the path, but it did not. After specifying the full path, everything works fine.